# Disable/Enable several items on CheckedChange event

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have several checkboxes and a textbox. When I check a certain checkbox, it will disable the textbox and other specified checkboxes.

The code works fine for the textbox. When I add the `else` statement it still works for the textbox, but does not work for the checkboxes. If I omit the `else` and only use the `if` to disable them, it works. I need it to re-enable them if the checkbox is unchecked.

I have all of the checkboxes in question in a panel.

```
    private void noModemChkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (noModemChkbox.Checked == true)
        {
            custModemText.Enabled = false;
            pwrCbx.Enabled = false;
            e1Cbx.Enabled = false;
            e2Cbx.Enabled = false;
            e3Cbx.Enabled = false;
            e4Cbx.Enabled = false;
            dslblinkCbx.Enabled = false;
            enetCbx.Enabled = false;
            dslCbx.Enabled = false;
            inetCbx.Enabled = false;
            inetredCbx.Enabled = false;
            wlanCbx.Enabled = false;
            activityChkbox.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
            custModemText.Enabled = true;
        pwrCbx.Enabled = true;
        e1Cbx.Enabled = true;
        e2Cbx.Enabled = true;
        e3Cbx.Enabled = true;
        e4Cbx.Enabled = true;
        dslblinkCbx.Enabled = true;
        enetCbx.Enabled = true;
        dslCbx.Enabled = true;
        inetCbx.Enabled = true;
        inetredCbx.Enabled = true;
        wlanCbx.Enabled = true;
        activityChkbox.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to put braces around the else statement:

```
private void noModemChkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (noModemChkbox.Checked == true)
    {
        custModemText.Enabled = false;
        pwrCbx.Enabled = false;
        e1Cbx.Enabled = false;
        e2Cbx.Enabled = false;
        e3Cbx.Enabled = false;
        e4Cbx.Enabled = false;
        dslblinkCbx.Enabled = false;
        enetCbx.Enabled = false;
        dslCbx.Enabled = false;
        inetCbx.Enabled = false;
        inetredCbx.Enabled = false;
        wlanCbx.Enabled = false;
        activityChkbox.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        custModemText.Enabled = true;
        pwrCbx.Enabled = true;
        e1Cbx.Enabled = true;
        e2Cbx.Enabled = true;
        e3Cbx.Enabled = true;
        e4Cbx.Enabled = true;
        dslblinkCbx.Enabled = true;
        enetCbx.Enabled = true;
        dslCbx.Enabled = true;
        inetCbx.Enabled = true;
        inetredCbx.Enabled = true;
        wlanCbx.Enabled = true;
        activityChkbox.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Wouldn't this be much simpler? :

```
private void noModemChkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool bEnabled = !noModemChkbox.Checked;

    custModemText.Enabled = bEnabled;
    pwrCbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    e1Cbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    e2Cbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    e3Cbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    e4Cbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    dslblinkCbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    enetCbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    dslCbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    inetCbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    inetredCbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    wlanCbx.Enabled = bEnabled;
    activityChkbox.Enabled = bEnabled;
}
```

Comment: Lol nice catch i didnt even notice it and neither did VS. Thanks!

Comment: The alternative is certainly much simpler yet is above my ability at this point as i do not fully understand whats going on in that code but thanks for the example i will do some research to understand how it works!

Comment: @Nabbic - it will set a temporary boolean variable to the opposite of whatever the checked value is for noModemChkbox (! means not), then this value is applied to all enabled values (+1 btw)

Comment: +1 for showing a better way as well as pointing out the issue.

Comment: This also makes it easier to add a new component that is controlled by this checkbox. You only need to add it in once place rather than the if and else blocks.

Comment: @Nabbic: VS didn't complain becaues your code is still syntactically correct. If brackets arn't used, the next statement is treated as the only code in the else block (as Ryan points out in his answer). This is also how it works if you leave off the brackets in the if (and for/while/do-while/etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You need brackets around your else like the following:

```
else
{
    custModemText.Enabled = true;
    pwrCbx.Enabled = true;
    e1Cbx.Enabled = true;
    e2Cbx.Enabled = true;
    e3Cbx.Enabled = true;
    e4Cbx.Enabled = true;
    dslblinkCbx.Enabled = true;
    enetCbx.Enabled = true;
    dslCbx.Enabled = true;
    inetCbx.Enabled = true;
    inetredCbx.Enabled = true;
    wlanCbx.Enabled = true;
    activityChkbox.Enabled = true;
}
```

Your original code actually gets interpreted like this:

```
else
{
    custModemText.Enabled = true;
}

pwrCbx.Enabled = true;
e1Cbx.Enabled = true;
e2Cbx.Enabled = true;
e3Cbx.Enabled = true;
e4Cbx.Enabled = true;
dslblinkCbx.Enabled = true;
enetCbx.Enabled = true;
dslCbx.Enabled = true;
inetCbx.Enabled = true;
inetredCbx.Enabled = true;
wlanCbx.Enabled = true;
activityChkbox.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot didnt even notice it.

Comment: @Nabbic No problem. That is why it is always a best practice to put brackets even if it is just a one line body.

Answer (score 1):

You need brackets `{}` around everything you want in the else clause (if you have more than one statement):

```
private void noModemChkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (noModemChkbox.Checked == true)
    {
        custModemText.Enabled = false;
        pwrCbx.Enabled = false;
        e1Cbx.Enabled = false;
        e2Cbx.Enabled = false;
        e3Cbx.Enabled = false;
        e4Cbx.Enabled = false;
        dslblinkCbx.Enabled = false;
        enetCbx.Enabled = false;
        dslCbx.Enabled = false;
        inetCbx.Enabled = false;
        inetredCbx.Enabled = false;
        wlanCbx.Enabled = false;
        activityChkbox.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        custModemText.Enabled = true;
        pwrCbx.Enabled = true;
        e1Cbx.Enabled = true;
        e2Cbx.Enabled = true;
        e3Cbx.Enabled = true;
        e4Cbx.Enabled = true;
        dslblinkCbx.Enabled = true;
        enetCbx.Enabled = true;
        dslCbx.Enabled = true;
        inetCbx.Enabled = true;
        inetredCbx.Enabled = true;
        wlanCbx.Enabled = true;
        activityChkbox.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```